End Fed Ant w/o Tuner: Using 1:1 To Reflect
Imagine I have a 34 foot length of 12 gauge stranded wire that is my end fed  20 Mhz antenna, set up as a sloper.
I've attached a 49:1 at the feed point and a 1:1 Guanella after that, then 20 feet of RG8X coax with 10 small ferrites on the outside of the cable at the RF output.
My thinking, is that any mismatch and reflection from the 49:1, will stop at the 1:1 and
reflect back into the antenna.
Thus, I will not need a tuner on this setup. Also, the shield of my coax will not be  part of the antenna system.
The draw backs will be energy consumed by the two transformers.
Is this thinking correct ?


The lossiest parts of your antenna system are (1) the antenna being close to the ground and (2) 49:1 transformer.
1:1 Guanella has a very low loss if designed and constructed well.
There is no such thing as "any mismatch and reflection from the 49:1, will stop at the 1:1 and reflect back into the antenna." Any reflected power caused by a mismatch will be wasted. (Re-reflection is a popular story among amateurs, but it was created based on an incorrect theory.)
If you are interested in 20MHz, where a low takeoff angle is of the highest interest (NVIS won't happen at that frequency), your best option is to make the antenna vertical or horizontal with height rather than a sloper. Sloper is more effective for low bands for a mix of NVIS and DX (compromised mix, that is).
Also, 49:1 transformer is one of the most lossy transformers commonly used in the feedline. If an alternate antenna design does not require 49:1, I would consider that if you are concerned about efficiency.

Thank you. I hate 49:1 transformers. I tried to make it "better" by constructing 4 turns on the primary. As for power dissipation vs reflection: I'll have to read about that. If reflection doesn't exist, then in your opinion, are balanced line Zeplin dipole antennas not that great ? Also thanks for the NVIS heads up. I'm using a sloper b/c the desert has few trees and hauling a tall pole around is difficult and they ain't cheap. I'll swtich to a 40 m.

lastly, the ground in my hiking area is desert. It's bone dry although it's filled with minerals. I don't think there's a lot of ground losses. I should find out.

Dry ground is the worst, saltwater is the lowest ground loss. I personally use verticals with a loop radial for SOTA and POTA. I'm more high band, DX oriented op. I occasionally go to 60/40/30m for regional hunters, just to say hi, but those don't need to be optimal performance (to me). You can find me on QRZ and SOTA reflector for more details of my antenna.

I'm using "ground loss" differently and perhaps incorrectly. I think of coupling to ground as loss as the ground doesn't radiate. Conductors like salt water would reflect and even help a radial system. That's how I think...is that wrong ??

Ground loss is a non-radiating series resistance coming from outside the antenna in the antenna's equivalent circuit. Loss and reflection are two different phenomena associated with ground, so please do not mix them. This is a whole another topic now, though.

I thought it about more and understand. Thanks again.

Reflection back into antenna being incorrect is an issue. I need more information. IIRC, only real resistance can be burned up as power. How does the reactance get eaten by the 49:1 ? We can open a new question.

Please search my past / recent answers by searching for Walter Maxwell. He wrote an influential book with elaborate stories spreading incorrect information, cited by many amateurs.

Your design is better than an antenna that uses a full 1/4 wave ground mounted counterpoise; for one reason, if you think a 49:1 transformer is lossy, see how much loss you get when half of your useful antenna current is lying on the ground!
If the 49:1 UnUn transformer bothers you, then center-feed the antenna, like this:

Your feed-point impedance will be very close to 50 Ohms, and all you will need is a choke, or some ferrites on the coax at the feed-point, or your 1:1 Guanella BalUn, instead of a choke or ferrites.
About using the Guanella BalUn the way you do in your diagram, you can't!  The Guanella is not simply a choke, it's a BalUn, in other words, it puts differential voltage & current on each leg, and then you are going into an UnUn, and that will probably cause common-mode problems you won't be able to solve.
Also, I'll never argue about ferrites, or a choke at the radio's coax terminal, as choking coax there can make your receive quieter in noisy environments.
Read more about slopers here:
https://www.hamradiosecrets.com/ham-radio-hf-antenna.html

Guanella 1:1 transformer is a common mode choke and a balun. It does not create a new common mode current. It simply increases the common mode impedance to the circuit. The way it functions as a balun is the same. You can use Guanella 1:1 without having it serve as a balun without any problem.

I like the idea of a center fed sloper. I  agree that a Guanella is not putting signal on the coax shield as it's a common mode filter. The main reason for end fed is the easy and speed of setup. I think a CF will be just as fast though.
